# Soft Keyboard in android not shown when API calls

Tags: android

After calling API in response I written this . It is not working

```
 ProgressOverlay.removeProgress();
                et_name.clearFocus();
                et_name.setFocusable(true);
                et_name.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                et_name.requestFocusFromTouch();
                et_name.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(et_name, 0);
                    }
                }, 50);
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this works

```
inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(et_name, 2);
```